# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, datasource, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am working on Spring MVC application. I am getting the following exception when I am trying to run the application:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
```

I tried to follow other posts in stackverflow and implemented based on commnets but nothing has fixed the issue. Please find the files below:

Servlet-Context.xml

```
<beans:bean id="SearchResultsServiceDAOImpl"  class="com.easyFinder.app.ServiceDAOImpl.SearchResultsServiceDAOImpl">
          <beans:property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL"/>
    <beans:property name="username" value="sysman"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value="orcl"/>
</beans:bean>
```

SearchresultsServiceDAOImpl.java

```
private DataSource dataSource;
public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

public String enterIntoNewEntrytable(Date date, String message) {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();
    List args = new ArrayList();
    String query = "INSERT INTO NEW_ENTRY VALUES ('1',?,?)";
    jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    args.add(date);
    args.add(message);
    jdbcTemplate.update(query,args);
    return null;
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/app] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'dataSource' is required
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcAccessor.afterPropertiesSet(JdbcAccessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.<init>(JdbcTemplate.java:168)
    at com.easyFinder.app.ServiceDAOImpl.SearchResultsServiceDAOImpl.enterIntoNewEntrytable(SearchResultsServiceDAOImpl.java:28)
    at com.easyFinder.app.SearchActionController.home(SearchActionController.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
<beans:bean id="searchResultsServiceDAO"  class="com.easyFinder.app.ServiceDAOImpl.SearchResultsServiceDAOImpl">
    <beans:property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
</beans:bean>
```

Interface

```
public interface SearchresultsServiceDAO {
   public String enterIntoNewEntrytable(Date date, String message);
}
```

Then

```
public class SearchresultsServiceDAOImpl 
    implements SearchresultsServiceDAO {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public String enterIntoNewEntrytable(Date date, String message) {
        //Then you can use
        Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        // ...
        return null;
    }

}
```

if you want to inject the datasource into `JdbcTemplate` use

```
<beans:bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"> 
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</beans:bean>
```

and use it this way

```
@Autowired 
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
```

You might also need `<context:annotation-config/>` depending on your configuration

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `interface` definitions in configuration instead of `implementation`.

You have currently defined which refers to implementation,

```
<beans:bean id="SearchResultsServiceDAOImpl"  class="com.easyFinder.app.ServiceDAOImpl.SearchResultsServiceDAOImpl">
          <beans:property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource" />    
</beans:bean>
```

Instead update it too (Please verify the path),

```
<beans:bean id="searchResultsServiceDAO"  class="com.easyFinder.app.ServiceDAO.SearchResultsServiceDAO">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />    
</beans:bean>
```

I see that you have used `constructor` injection. But you can use annotation based implementation approach to `inject` beans because this will remove requirement to pass the `dataSource` in each of the DAO constructors.

Check for `@Autowired` documentation.

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the DataSource and the JdbcTemplate are initialized and that the getJdbcTemplate is defined in the flow of the data (anywhere, but should be done). Below is an example:

```
@Autowired
protected DataSource dataSource;

/** Spring JDBC helper. */
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

/**
 * Gets the jdbc template. Instantiates on first call.
 * 
 * @return the jdbc template
 */
public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
    if (null == jdbcTemplate) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
    return jdbcTemplate;
}
```

I got the same exception when I called the impl class directly, but these were initiated in the base class.